# Magento - How to use the JoinTable function in EE 1.9

Tags: php, mysql, magento

We have a problem after upgrading to 1.9.1 EE of magento. On a custom script we used to make a join with another table by this way, and it always worked fine.

```
$collection->joinTable('sales_flat_order_item','order_id=entity_id', array('sku', 'qty_ordered', 'qty_invoiced', 'udropship_vendor') , 'sales_flat_order_item.udropship_vendor="'.$this->vendorid.'"', 'right');
$collection->groupByAttribute(array('entity_id'));
```

But after the upgrade we've got the error message: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Order_Collection::joinTable().

Does anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 3):

Order Collection now is represented by a flat table. Thus you can add filters via standard Varien_Db_Select property of this collection:

```
$select = $collection->getSelect();
$select->join(
        array('o_item' => 'sales_flat_order_item'),
        'o_item.order_id = main_table.entity_id AND o_item.udropship_vendor = "' . $this->vendorid . '"',
        array('sku', 'qty_ordered', 'qty_invoiced', 'udropship_vendor')
    )
    ->group('main_table.entity_id');
```

It is the answer to this question.

However, additionally I should point to some issues in the code snippet, you gave in the question:

1. It's better to overwrite this
   collection for your store and
   put this logic into newly created public
   method of a collection model. It is better than manipulate collection's fields
   directly.
2. The join identifier 'right' was
   never permitted for joining the EAV
   collection tables. Internally, as unknown identifier, it was mapped
   to 'inner join'. It is very
   different from possibly intended
   'right outer join'. Should you
   rewrite logic? Or does 'inner join'
   act as intended?
3. The 'sku', 'qty_ordered',
   'qty_invoiced' fields are ambiguous.
   They are not reliable as they are
   taken from unknown order item (or
   even from different items), that was
   joined to the order by 'udropship'
   condition.
4. It's possible, that you should quote
   '$this->vendorid', if it's a string.
   Or cast it to int, if it's integer.
   It is not safe just to concat vendor id to
   the string and surround it with double
   quotes.